# Checkbox Checked Enables Textbox

Tags: forms, wordpress

I have created a form that enables a text box when a certain checkbox is checked, however the text I enter in the form is not stored in my Classipress/wordpress install. What do I need to do to fix this code so it stores what the user enters in the text box?

```
 <li>
            <div class="labelwrapper">
                <label>Certifications: </label>
                                </div>

            <ol class="checkboxes">


                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cp_certifications_list" id="cp_certifications_1" value="TEFL" class="checkboxlist " onclick="addRemoveCheckboxValues(this, 'cp_certifications_value')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TEFL                        </li> <!-- #checkbox -->

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cp_certifications_list" id="cp_certifications_2" value=" TESOL" class="checkboxlist " onclick="addRemoveCheckboxValues(this, 'cp_certifications_value')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TESOL                        </li> <!-- #checkbox -->

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cp_certifications_list" id="cp_certifications_3" value=" CELTA" class="checkboxlist " onclick="addRemoveCheckboxValues(this, 'cp_certifications_value')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CELTA                        </li> <!-- #checkbox -->

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cp_certifications_list" id="cp_certifications_4" value=" ESL Degree" class="checkboxlist " onclick="addRemoveCheckboxValues(this, 'cp_certifications_value')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ESL Degree                        </li> <!-- #checkbox -->

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cp_certifications_list" id="cp_certifications_5" value=" Teaching Certificate" class="checkboxlist " onclick="addRemoveCheckboxValues(this, 'cp_certifications_value')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teaching Certificate                        </li> <!-- #checkbox -->

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cp_certifications_list" id="cp_certifications_6" value=" English Degree" class="checkboxlist " onclick="addRemoveCheckboxValues(this, 'cp_certifications_value')">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;English Degree                        </li> <!-- #checkbox -->

                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cp_certifications_list" id="cp_certifications_7" value=" Other" class="checkboxlist " onclick="document.getElementById('cp_certifications_8').disabled=(this.checked)?0:1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Other                        </li> <!-- #checkbox -->
                    <li>
                        <input name="cp_certifications_list" id="cp_certifications_8" type="text" minlength="2" value="" class="text " disabled /></li>
                <input type="hidden" name="cp_certifications" id="cp_certifications_value" value="" style="display:none;" />

            </ol> <!-- #checkbox-wrap -->

            <div class="clr"></div>


        </li>
```

Comment: First of all, I would think about the markup here. You're having an ordered list _inside_ of a list-item. Is this really necessary? Second, you didn't provide enough markup here. Where is the <form> - element and where does it submit to? Is the rest of the form submitted properly and only the value of the text-box is missing, or is nothing stored?

Comment: Here is a link to the entire form paste, it is long, which is why I did not pop it in here: http://pastebin.com/8M9PmAAN

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the appropriate forum for this question. I think you may have more success over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com . I don't know how the Classipress Wordpress theme works, but you may want to ask on their forums or ask their developers what people typically do.

Otherwise I think there are two options left to you. One is to createa Wordpress plugin. Wordpress plugins have a means for saving information to the Wordpress database.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Saving_Plugin_Data_to_the_Database

The other option is to setup your own database. You'll need to submit your form to a server that can postprocess the data and write it to a database. Sounds like you may be in over your head. You may want to try and enlist a programmer friend for help.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know about wordpress.stackexchange.com. I am going to try there.